# Redirection in cake PHP, hide app/webroot bit

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a site done with cakePHP and I access to the sites there like:

```
http://example.com/site1
```

Which is converted to:

```
http://example.com/app/webroot/site1
```

As I've searched and seen [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess) or searching here in stack-overflow this is the normal behaviour but I'd like that the user actually doesn't see the **app/webroot** bit.

Is that possible?

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

# CakePHP part
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the `app/webroot` bit is being displayed in the URL address bar when you go to `http://example.com/site1`?

Comment: Yes, the user types http://example.com/site1 and it becomes http://example.com/app/webroot/site1 in the adress bar

Comment: @user761076 that is *not* normal. The app folder should be above your document root and / should map physically to the app/webroot folder.

Comment: So, where's the problem? thanks

Comment: Cake comes with its own .htaccess files (i.e see [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/.htaccess)) which will work normally. Do you have all three present in your application? Are they all processed by apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed all the instructions to install CakePHP, the URL **without** `/app/webroot` should work too. If it is not working, re-download all the `.htaccess` files from the CakePHP repo. There are three files.

To get rid of the `/app/webroot`, i.e. never see that path on any URL, you may edit or create a `VirtualHost` with a `DocumentRoot` pointing to the absolute path of your webroot.

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot /absolute/path-to/app/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

This is not possible if you are on a shared server. If you are on a managed VPS or dedicated server, you need to contact your hosting. If it is unmanaged, you can do it yourself.